# How to connect server to printer via JAVA

Tags: java, printing

There are a few requirements:

1. There is a system running on a server. Server connects with many printers. 

2. Depends on the document types, server will request the right printer to print out the pages.

May I know is there any examples that I can refer to?

Comment: And how much is the budget for this project?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LPD (Line Printer Daemon) implementation in Java](http://lpdspooler.sourceforge.net/)

This accepts print jobs over the network and captures them, so a programmer can then manipulate these print jobs.  Processing of the print files is now straight forward.  By extending the HandlerInterface a developer can do whatever he wishes with the PrintJob.  Right now I have implemented writing the PrintJob to disk once we have received it, and I am working on writing the PrintJob to the default printer.  Eventually I hope to write the file to a database or network (say a JetDirect).  Please check out the class org.simoes.lpd.HandlerInterface.java to see how easy it is to handle your own PrintJobs.

Or

[Cups4J - Java printing library for CUPS/IPP](http://www.cups4j.org/):

This new version comes with some new features and one API change that can break your existing code without compile errors - so please be very careful. Print job attributes provided via attribute map need to be sparated by '#' instead of ' ' in order to allow blanks within attribute values.